# Appending a DegreeSymbol in a string

Tags: c++, utf-8

I want to append a degree symbol to the string for example 55.66° so I use 
    
     `std::wostringstream stream;
     stream<<"55.66"<<"°";`

then I convert it into wstring like  stream.str()
the output I Get is 55.66Â°

An extra A is added.How can I remove that?
I have also tried with stream<<"55.66"<"\u00B0"

Comment: How are you generating the output?  Can you show that code?

Comment: You're probably writing `C2 B0` to the stream, and wherever your outputting to isn't set to UTF-8.

Comment: i am using stream.str() and pass this wstring to filltextObjectForGraphicItem(item,stream.str(),textdata);

Comment: How can outputting be set to UTF-8??

Comment: @Ankushsharma That's going to be hard to provide unless you tell us what you are outputting to and on what platform.

Comment: I am using visual Studio .i am outputting it to DICOm file.SO u can it as a text file.I am writing into a txt file.Its an X64 system

Comment: @Ankushsharma and what are you using to look at the text file?

Comment: There is a Dicom Editor

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't convert a wide string to a narrow C string. Converting to `const char *` won't work, you have to convert it to `const wchar_t *`.

Now, hopefully you didn't do this:

```
cstr = stream.str().c_str();
```

because `str()` returns a temporary string object; when the statement has finished, it's deallocated, and its `c_str()` pointer has been invalidated. So **if** you did this, you better extract the stream's string in a stand-alone variable instead.

Comment: I am converting to wstring to stream.str().the only problem I m facing is outputting it correctly

Comment: I have modified the question